# How can I integrate with the Windows Action Centre maintenance?

Tags: windows

Foxit Reader had a bug with the Firefox plugin that led to Firefox crashing when PDFs were opened. The Windows Action Centre was able to suggest a fix for the bug and link to a relevant thread in a forum. How can I similarly integrate my application with the Windows Action Centre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done via registering your application with [Windows Error Reporting](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/winlogo/maintain/StartWER.mspx). When you do this, you will have a dashboard of your most "popular" crashes, and if you find solutions to them, you can submit responses with links to how to fix it.